# Will we ever be able to understand history with 100% accuracy

Tags: ancient-history, historiography, science

First of all, I am not a historian or anything of the like, but this question was bothering me for quite some time.

As far as I understand, the current methodology historians use to explain our history is mostly based on theoreticizing. Like reading certain works some long dead person wrote, digging up certain items etc etc. Can we ever be 100% sure that what we know is a hard truth? (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Let's take hieroglyphics as an example. Are we really certain that our translation of those is correct? What actual proof do we have?

I was reading some mathematical problem out of the Moscow Papyrus and there were still people there that were fighting over what the scribe writing those might have meant.

My question is will we ever achieve such a scientific milestone that we will be able to truly understand *for a fact* every event in history so we wouldn't have to theoreticize about it and just say what *most likely* happened?

Comment: Since we're all human (fallible, biased, etc,), our view points are consequently subjective. What constitutes the objective 'truth' is, therefore, always going to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: To be 100% accurate, you'd need to collect every single piece of information about an event. The larger the event or the further back in history (or both), the harder it is to be able to do that. The best you can hope for is to be reasonably accurate about the important details (and hope that any missing details are actually insignificant).

Comment: Humans can't [write a bug free computer program](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195571/is-it-possible-to-reach-absolute-zero-bug-state-for-large-scale-software), can't [prove all truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems), and can't [*know* all history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method). History, Science, and in fact life in general, is about doing the best we can right now with our limited resources and capabilities. Perfection is for the divine alone.

Comment: @T.E.D. maybe I went to far with the phrasing of my question. I meant more like to have a scientific method that provides *more thruthful* analysis of history. Say we are able to tap into the minds of those before us using extracts of their DNA or something( I'm just coming up with this randomly )

Comment: @T.E.D.: Humans certainly can write bug-free computer programs.  I've done so myself, many times.  What they can't do is guarantee that every computer program they write is bug-free.

Comment: Define accuracy. Just to pick an example, let's look at the news.  Consider the amount of investment that multiple international news networks spend analyzing and explaining the news - current day events where most of the information is available.   Yet they don't agree.  The bias' they bring to the effort _are part of the truth_.  This is an excellent question about historiography.  We don't seek _truth_ in science; we seek greater explanatory power.  Bailor's analysis of the revolution was superior to the predecessors not because it was _true_ but because it accounted for more facts.

Comment: We don't judge hieroglyph translation by "truth", but by whether the method permits us to translate other hieroglyphs.  In general science doesn't measure "truth" - we have no way of directly observing subatomic particles or galaxies, or most of the other subjects of modern science.  But if the theory and method grants us more predictive power, it is judged to be better than the predecessor.  In short, you're asking a good question, but one that history has no intent of answering

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because to the extent that the question is focussed, it is asking for perfect certainty which is impossible in *anything*.  I'm sure there are some interesting questions which resemble this one but are answerable and the asker should consider asking one of those, instead.

Comment: This level of certainty isn't even possible in physics, much less history.

Comment: I, hereby, solemnly promise that in exactly 10 billion years from now, we (whoever "we" might be) will know everything there is to know (whatever this might be) with 100% accuracy.

Comment: All we have from the past are memories put together, bits of proof, stories and theories. Yes, some things are lost forever, and after sufficient time all is lost. But it's the same in the life of each individual, we need to be able to tell the story of out lives, to tell the past as long as we live or have a sound mind. History is the memory of mankind, but articulated in a more rational manner than individual memories. It is a science, even if its results are not absolutely certain. Science is not about absolute certainty.

Answer (score 6):

To address the question about Egyptian Hieroglyphics, we can be sure that our readings are mostly correct. The initial key to reading them was the [Rosetta Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone), which had the same text in three different languages:

- Greek, which was well-known.
- Demotic Egyptian, an ancestor of Coptic. This was comparatively easy to decipher.
- Hieroglyphic Egyptian, which was older and much harder.

Figuring out [ancient Egyptian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decipherment_of_ancient_Egyptian_scripts) was not simple, because the script works rather differently from most written languages, but it was gradually achieved. It was already known that the [spoken Egyptian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_language) was an ancestor of Coptic, which is still used by the Coptic Church in Egypt. That gave significant clues to pronunciation and grammar. As understanding developed, it became possible to trace changes in the language and its writing through the history of Egypt, and those changes were reasonably in accord with what we know from other regions of the world about the way languages change over time.

There are a great many surviving samples of Egyptian, on papyri, in tombs, and lots of inscriptions on statues and temples. And they all make sense. At this point, it becomes completely implausible that we're misinterpreting the script in any fundamental way, because there are just too many texts that make sense. There were [spurious claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasius_Kircher#Egyptology) of translation before the script was understood, but they fell apart when applied to a text that the author didn't study.

Further, the ability to read Egyptian was important in deciphering [Old Persian Cuneiform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuneiform#External_confirmation_through_Egyptian_hieroglyphs_(1823)), and our readings of that language are internally consistent, making the idea that we have Egyptian wrong even less plausible.

Finally, new bilingual texts are occasionally discovered. The readings of the Egyptian text, which we've never seen before, are in accordance with the other language(s) of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Of course we cannot be sure. Even for relatively public recent events, with TV reporters recording whatever the camera was pointed at and access to government records, we can't know what wasn't recorded or if the people who wrote the records misrepresented the truth.

What you call "theoretical" might be better described as "taking a critical look at sources." The historian looks at as many records as feasible and asks the questions:

- Who wrote it?
- What was the intention of the writer?
- Who was the audience?
- Are the claims consistent with physical evidence and other records?

A bit like a judge and jury looking at a criminal case. And just as in the justice system, every now and then the historians get it wrong. Sceptics or minority opinions might have been right for all the right reasons, or because even a stopped clock shows the right time twice a day.

Comment: Take a look at my comment on my question. I am more concerned with improvements in other scientific areas. Be able to extract some new info from the DNA? Say we invent **time travel**...

Comment: I mean will we forever live with never ever truly understanding ancient Egypt, Greece etc..

Comment: @MichaelMunta, there are some people claiming faster than light travel is possible, and that it implies time travel, but practical time travel belongs more to the fictional settings of Worldbuilding Stack Exchange than on History SE.

Comment: @MichaelMunta: Inventing time travel would mean that *nothing* could thereafter be predicted. It's excluded from any reasonable attempt to predict the future on those grounds. If you're thinking of ideas you've got from Star Trek, Sci-fi movies, or comic books about what science might develop in the future, discard them all now. Everything Hollywood tells you about science is wrong.